# How to solve "new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?"

Tags: python, etl, python-3.5

We have data where csv files are generated using pandas and uploaded into s3. Downstream uses stitch were we are encountering this issue. in python we are using utf8-sig as encoding and ends up having failure often. is there a way to cleanse this from python itself. and how to identify the special character causing this issue .i have tried vi and other editors,till now unable to find the real issue.

Comment: Can you share some sample data ? It would help us better in understanding your problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.